# Remote Desktop connection blocked by group policy, but only when started from cmd.exe

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-8.1

On my workstation at a client's office, I have some custom scripts that allow me to RDP-connect to various server machines without having to manually open Remote Desktop connection, enter server name and credentials etc.

This worked great until the client migrated my machine to Windows 8.1. Now, I can still use Remote Desktop manually (i.e. by starting it with the mouse), but when I use a script that invokes `mstsc.exe`, I get the error message

```
This program is blocked by group policy
```

I understand that administrators can block usage of this program. What I don't get is why the program can be used *manually*, but not via a script.

Any ideas?

Note that when used via a script, Remote Desktop would still display warnings like "This connection might be unsafe" etc. So, I don't think it can be used by malicious scripts, since the user has to confirm the connection manually.

Comment: Can you open cmd on its own?

Comment: @Drifter104 Yes. But when I enter `mytsc` in cmd`, I get the error message.

Comment: Put the logic on your question that shows what the custom script it doing exactly and maybe that'll offer some clue to someone for further guidance. An RDP saved session or icon is really just a text file with parameters set. But I'd suggest sharing part of the logic in your script that's not working and tell whether it's batch, etc. if it's not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the scripts I'm talking about are on a network share, because they are in my personal folder.

Running scripts from network shares is blocked by group policy.